# How to prevent every component from rendering until it's props are fetched?

Tags: reactjs

I have many components which on load fetch data, and I don't want to show them until the data is fetched because they require many checks on code, like check if the data exist and then display it, etc .. and if I render my component only after the fetch, I wouldn't need all those checks

Things I've tried and done already are (lets take this component for example)

1.check if user is fetched, only after display data

```
 const Private = ({ user, getUserDetails }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getUserDetails ();
  }, []);

  if (!isAuth()) return <Redirect to='/signin' />;
  return (
    <div>
     {user && <h1>Hello {user.name}</h1>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect((state) => ({ user: state.auth.user }), {
  getUserDetails,
})(Private);
```

2. if user doesn't exist, return null / empty div

```
    const Private = ({ user, getUserDetails }) => {
      useEffect(() => {
        getUserDetails ();
      }, []);

      if (!isAuth()) return <Redirect to='/signin' />;
      if (isAuth() && !user) return null;
      return (
        <div>
         {user && <h1>Hello {user.name}</h1>}
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default connect((state) => ({ user: state.auth.user }), {
      getUserDetails,
    })(Private);
```

Now both ways work, but I don't want to do that for every single component, I'm going to have many components that require different fetched data, there must be a global solution to do that?

Hope anyone could help me and understood me :)
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You can make a hoc: `const withUser = Component => props => props.user? <Component {...props} /> : null` and pass `withUser(Private)` to connect

Comment: Thanks, I've thought about it, but I'm going to have many components and each will require different kind of fetched props, so I should make bunch of HOC's for all of them? @HMR

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loading` property, which you will change in your last request, so you can tell that you have done all needed requests.

```
async function getUserData() { //just for the example
  const request = await fetch('http://example.com/user', {
     method: "GET",
  });

  return await request.json();
}
```

and in your components you can have this.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
   loading: true,
   user: false
});

useEffect(() => {
   getUserData().then((result) => {
       setState({
          loading: false,
          user: result
       })
   })
})

if (state.loading) {
  return null;
}
```